# Error "FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)" even in default default flutter web project

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

Whenever I create a new flutter web project, it gives me the same error: `Unexpected Character (at character 1)`.

When I run `webdev serve` it gives a blank screen and stops.
and, on webdev daemon I get the error.

I made no changes in the code, and executed it as it was, that is, the default flutter web project.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled, tried flutter clean, but none of this is working:

Further details are given below:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Not Found
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1392:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1259:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:924:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:29:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:493:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:151:41)
#6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:94:10)
#7      parse (package:source_maps/parser.dart:27:15)
#8      Sources.scriptParsed (package:dwds/src/debugging/sources.dart:62:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#10     CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:81:11)
#11     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#14     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
#15     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
#16     WipDomain.eventStream.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:webkit_inspection_protocol/webkit_inspection_protocol.dart:301:26)
#17     _HandlerEventSink.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:228:7)
#18     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
#19     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#21     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
#22     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:707:11)
#23     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:667:7)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
pub failed (255)
```

My main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint" action
          // from the Flutter Inspector in Android Studio, or the "Toggle Debug
          // Paint" command in Visual Studio Code) to see the wireframe for each
          // widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Hello, World!',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/ipshitag/hello_world/tree/master/helloworld

Comment: I don’t know about flutter for web but it looks like some code is trying to parse some json but instead it is receiving the text “Not Found”.

Comment: But i have not added any json files. If there is any by default, where is it? I can't figure out

Comment: Can you please post your project or some sample code?

Comment: It the default flutter project. But still, I am adding my main.dart and you can see all the files at https://github.com/ipshitag/hello_world/tree/master/helloworld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a webdev bug on Windows that was fixed in webdev v2.5.0:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/514
- https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/pull/563

Run `pub global activate webdev` to update to the latest version.